# The method execute(String, JSONArray, String) of type Share must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: cordova, share, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova-2.4.0 and when I add "share" plugin to "src" I get the error "The method execute(String, JSONArray, String) of type Share must override or implement a supertype method". I don't know how to resolve this Java error. Code of my Java file where I am getting error is:

```
 /**
 * 
 * Phonegap share plugin for Android
 * Kevin Schaul 2011
 *
 */

package com.schaul.plugins.share;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;

public class Share extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = args.getJSONObject(0);
            doSendIntent(jo.getString("subject"), jo.getString("text")); 
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    private void doSendIntent(String subject, String text) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0);
    }

}
```